# OneToMany relationship doesn't save foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, rest

I am doing a `OneToMany` relationship in a hibernate query. It's working fine but the `donorId` is not going to the `blood` table.

Donor Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DONOR")
public class Donor {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int donorId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int age;
private String cnic;
private String contactNumber;
private String homeNumber;
private String country;
private String city;
private String town;
private String streetNo;
private String houseNo;
private String email;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="donor")
private Set<Blood> blood;

public int getDonorId() {
    return donorId;
}
public void setDonorId(int donorId) {
    this.donorId = donorId;
}
public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}
public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}
public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}
public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
public String getCnic() {
    return cnic;
}
public void setCnic(String cnic) {
    this.cnic = cnic;
}
public String getContactNumber() {
    return contactNumber;
}
public void setContactNumber(String contactNumber) {
    this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
}
public String getHomeNumber() {
    return homeNumber;
}
public void setHomeNumber(String homeNumber) {
    this.homeNumber = homeNumber;
}
public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}
public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}
public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}
public String getTown() {
    return town;
}
public void setTown(String town) {
    this.town = town;
}
public String getStreetNo() {
    return streetNo;
}
public void setStreetNo(String streetNo) {
    this.streetNo = streetNo;
}
public String getHouseNo() {
    return houseNo;
}
public void setHouseNo(String houseNo) {
    this.houseNo = houseNo;
}
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Set<Blood> getBlood() {
    return blood;
}

public void setCity(Set<Blood> blood) {
    this.blood = blood;
}
}
```

Blood Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BLOOD")
public class Blood {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int bloodId;
private String bloodType;
private int price;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="donor_id")
private Donor donor;

public int getBloodId() {
    return bloodId;
}
public void setBloodId(int bloodId) {
    this.bloodId = bloodId;
}
public String getBloodType() {
    return bloodType;
}
public void setBloodType(String bloodType) {
    this.bloodType = bloodType;
}
public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public Donor getDepartment() {
    return donor;
}

public void setDonor(Donor donor) {
    this.donor = donor;
}   
}
```

Blood And Donor Object class:

```
public class BloodDonor {

private Donor donor;
private Blood blood;
public Donor getDonor() {
    return donor;
}
public void setDonor(Donor donor) {
    this.donor = donor;
}
public Blood getBlood() {
    return blood;
}
public void setBlood(Blood blood) {
    this.blood = blood;
}
}
```

BloodService Class:

```
public class BloodService {

SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;

public BloodDonor addNewBlood(BloodDonor bloodDonor){
    try{
        Blood blood = new Blood();
        Donor donor = new Donor();
        blood = (Blood)bloodDonor.getBlood();
        donor = (Donor)bloodDonor.getDonor();
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(donor);
        session.save(blood);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bloodDonor;
}
}
```

Blood Resource:

```
@Path("blood")
public class BloodResource {

BloodService bloodService = new BloodService();

@Path("new")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public BloodDonor addNewDonor(BloodDonor blood){
    return bloodService.addNewBlood(blood);
}
}
```

Console:

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
Hibernate: insert into DONOR (age, city, cnic, contactNumber, country, email, firstName, homeNumber, houseNo, lastName, streetNo, town, donorId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into BLOOD (bloodType, donor_id, price, bloodId) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First:**

Add CascadeType:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="donor")
private Set<Blood> blood;
```

**Second:**

Your Entities should be interconnected e.g. Donor's `Set<Blood>` should contain a link to Blood and Blood's field `Donor` should be set to that Donor instance.

So, lets try to interconnect them:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
Donor donor = new Donor();
Blood blood = new Blood();
blood.setDonor(donor);
HashSet<Blood> bloods = new HashSet<Blood>();
bloods.add(blood);
donor.setBlood(bloods);
//set some another fields if you want or they are NOT NULL in database
session.save(donor); //blood should be saved automatically due to cascade
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

This should work if everything is alright with your database structure.